# How do I specify a beamer theme's customisation options in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm trying to get [this beamer theme](http://amundy.co.uk/2014/01/11/new-introduction-to-beamer-theme.html) to work with R Markdown. Everything is working, except I can't work out how to tell R Markdown that I would like to include the "darktitle" option. In latex, this would look like `\usetheme[darktitle]{UniversityOfManchester}`.

At the moment, the output portion of my R Markdown header looks like this:

```
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: "UniversityOfManchester"
```

using `color_theme` doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

How about using the YAML option `header-includes`:

```
---
title: "Presentation"
output:
  beamer_presentation
header-includes:
  - \usetheme[darktitle]{UniversityOfManchester}
---
```